# How to create custom page before visit to store in Magento

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento website where Client wants that there should be a custom login page with only 2 fields username and password.That username and password is different as customer's registration.That will be static say username as abc and password as xyz.
When any one visit the site then he need to enter the username and pasword ony then he can view the store.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `basic access authentication` with set .htpasswd
2. You can move magento to subdirectory and place in root folder index.php with setting cookies
3. You can make own module and overwrite index controller (harder way)
4. You can add some code to magento's index.php that verifies if isset cookie's value (simpler way)(with a backup of original index.php):

   ```
   <?php
   if (!isset($_COOKIE['auth1'])){
       if(!isset($_POST['prelogin']) and !isset($_POST['prepass'])){
       //your form to post
   ?>
   <h1>Authentication Required</h1>
   <form method=post>
       <input type=text id=prelogin name=prelogin value=login>
       <input type=text id=password name=password value=password>
       <input type=submit value=submit>
   </form>
   <?php
       } else { //isset $_POST
       //...
       //your login+password check code
       //...
       setcookie("auth1", "your_md5(md5(pass))", time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
       header( 'Location: /index.php', true, 303 ); 
       }

   } else { //isset $_COOKIE['auth1']
   //...
   //other $_COOKIE['auth1'] checks here
   //....
   //main magento code
   }
   ?>
   ```

Next make diff patch with

```
    diff -u index.php.bak index.php > auth.patch
```

And after You upgrade your magento version simply launch

```
    patch index.php < auth.patch
```